# syntax error in MYSQL '1064'

Tags: php, mysql, sql, stored-procedures

I am unable to figure out the syntax error on the following query.. Help ? help ? help ?

```
CREATE PROCEDURE VoucherNumberGenerationForClass(
p_voucherType varchar(50),
p_yearId varchar(50),
p_NO longtext)
begin
IF((SELECT COUNT(suffixPrefixId)FROM tbl_SuffixPrefix WHERE (yearId = p_yearId) AND (voucherType = p_voucherType))<>0) 
    then
        DECLARE p_prefix VARCHAR(50);
        DECLARE p_startIndex int ;
        DECLARE p_suffix VARCHAR(50) ;
        DECLARE p_voucherNo VARCHAR(50) ;
        DECLARE p_prefix1 VARCHAR(50) ;
        DECLARE p_suffix1 VARCHAR(50) ;
            IF ((( SELECT COUNT(suffixPrefixId)FROM tbl_SuffixPrefix WHERE (yearId = p_yearId) AND (voucherType = p_voucherType) ))<>0 );
                    then
                        SET p_prefix=(SELECT ifnull(prefix,'') FROM tbl_SuffixPrefix WHERE (yearId = p_yearId) AND (voucherType = p_voucherType) );
                        SET p_suffix=(SELECT ifnull(suffix,'') FROM tbl_SuffixPrefix WHERE (yearId = p_yearId) AND (voucherType = p_voucherType) );

                        SET p_startIndex=(SELECT startIndex FROM tbl_SuffixPrefix WHERE (yearId = p_yearId) AND (voucherType = p_voucherType) );
                        SET p_startIndex=p_startIndex-1;

                            IF p_voucherType='Sales Invoice' 
                                then SET p_voucherNo=( SELECT ifnull(MAX(voucherNo+1),1) FROM tbl_SalesMaster WHERE((suffixPrefixId = (SELECT suffixPrefixId FROM tbl_SuffixPrefix WHERE (yearId = p_yearId) AND (voucherType = p_voucherType) ))
                                ) )
                            END if ;
                        SET p_voucherNo=p_voucherNo+p_startIndex ;
                        SET p_voucherNo= p_prefix+ p_voucherNo+p_suffix ;
                        SELECT p_voucherNo ;
            END if;
ELSEIF
    IF p_voucherType='Sales Invoice' 
        then SET p_voucherNo=( SELECT ifnull(MAX(voucherNo+1), 1) FROM tbl_SalesMaster ) ;
    SELECT p_voucherNo ;
END IF ;
end ;
```

```
ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'DECLA
RE p_prefix VARCHAR(50);
DECLARE p_startIndex int ;
DECLARE p_suffix VARCHA' at line 8
```

Comment: i think you need space in `ELSEIF` . like this `ELSE IF`

Comment: ELSE IF is in mssql not mysql .
mysql has ELSEIF

Comment: Why geven me -2  .. ;(

Answer (score 3):

Try putting your [`DECLARE` statements](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/declare.html) right after `BEGIN`:

> `DECLARE` is permitted only inside a `BEGIN ... END` compound statement and must be at its start, before any other statements.

Comment: @Gumbo Actually this is the right answer to OPs basic question(+1). Answer given by me is not in the picture unless OP puts declare statements outside if loop.

Answer (score 1):

Separate **COUNT(suffixPrefixId)FROM** as **COUNT(suffixPrefixId) FROM**

Answer (score 1):

Try removing semicolon from following `if` statement:

```
IF ((( SELECT COUNT(suffixPrefixId)FROM tbl_SuffixPrefix WHERE (yearId = p_yearId) AND (voucherType = p_voucherType) ))<>0 );
```